# How many wounds does a Rogue Trader character start with?

Tags: character-creation, rogue-trader

I do not seem to be able to see where in the RT core rulebook you can work out how many wounds a character starts with. During character creation there are modifiers to it, mostly through career path, but what exactly should the base figure be?

Based on the NPCs provided in the introductory campaign I would assume this figure would be around 20 to 25.

I would appreciate knowing what page actually states this.

Comment: Rogue Trader's core rules I believe have an ancestry that can be directly traced to WFRP 2e. In WFRP 2e starting wounds is a table with an X-axis of race and a Y-axis indexed on a single d10 (1d10). I would look in the section on chargen and seek an "obvious" table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Starting wounds depend on your homeworld, and can be found in the section starting on page 17 of the core rulebook.

For example, Deathworld characters start with (2 x Toughness Bonus) + (1d5 + 2)

Ex. Toughness = 35 (aka. bonus of 3). The 1d5 gives a 4.

For our death-worlder, this would result in; (2 x 3) + (4 + 2) = 12 wounds

Comment: oooh, It seems I have misunderstood what exactly those sections means. I took it to mean that the Toughness bonus is doubled, and a separate thing, they get +1d5+5 onto of there starting wounds, the starting wounds haven been worked out else where.

Comment: If you determine your origin bottom-up, is your "starting Toughness bonus" affected by other origin options (like Savant which gives a -5 to Toughness)?